# How to send Image from front end ajax to Flask Restful api

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, flask, flask-restful

I have created an API using Flask Restful in which the user can send a gemstone image and in return, he/she will receive a JSON with image name prediction.
My Flask Code is below

```
class Predict(Resource):
def get(self):
    image = request.files['image']
    image.save(os.path.join(app.config["IMAGE_UPLOADS"], image.filename))
    file_path = app.config['IMAGE_UPLOADS'] + "/" + image.filename
    prediction = {"pred": predict(file_path)}
    return jsonify(prediction)
api.add_resource(Predict, '/image')
```

predict is the function that takes the image path saved locally on the server.
when I use to test the API from python code i.e.

```
from requests import get

url = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/image"
img = open('./static/uploads/img.PNG', 'rb')
my_img = {'image': img}
pred = get(url, files=my_img)
print(pred.text)
```

it's work fine and I know in python code the image is an Object of type BufferedReader.
now I want to accept the file from the webform using ajax and formData. When I submit the form it returns 400 Bad Request
The [Ajax](https://github.com/Haseeb1604/ajax/blob/main/ajax.js) Function which I used in my code

```
<form id="myform">
    <input type="file" name="image" id="image">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<script src="../static/js/ajax.js"></script>
    <script>
        let form = document.querySelector("#myform");
        form.addEventListener("submit", e => {
            e.preventDefault();
            formdata = new FormData(form);
            ajax({
                url: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/image",
                method: "GET",
                data: formdata,
                onsuccess: (responseText, status, statusText)=>{
                    console.log(responseText);
                    console.log(status);
                    console.log(statusText);
                },
                onfailure: (status, statusText)=>{
                    console.log(status);
                    console.log(statusText);
                },
                contentType: false,
            });
        })
    </script>
```

Comment: you can't use `GET` when you're trying to send a file - what is this `ajax` function anyway?

Comment: But it works fine when I test it in python code. Ajax function code is linked you can check the code from GitHub https://github.com/Haseeb1604/ajax/blob/main/ajax.js.

Comment: Thanks, A lot It works. I don't know why but in python code it works on requests.get() method

Comment: perhaps pythin changes it to a POST behind the scenes because a GET makes no sense at all